# Format PHP string for post action

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a dropdown box to perform a selection in a form.

I have 4 values ('value1','value2','value3','value4'). Each are listed in the dropdown box. But I also want an option for all 4 values for example, here is the array I am currently using for the function that draws my dropdown menu:

```
$menuValues("'value1','value2','value3','value4'",'value1','value2','value3','value4');
```

This however produces an empty variable on the action page. I need to retain the single quotes around each value to feed a function that in turn drives a mysql query. Which is why I have used double-quotes to enclose the first value.

This is the dropdown function:

```
function frDrop($arr,$frm,$dropTitle) {
echo "<select name='".$frm."' id='".$frm."'><option value=''>".$dropTitle."...</option>";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: why not call the option "all"

Comment: what do you mean by an option for all 4 values? Do you mean that there is a text for example that says "select all of the above?"

Comment: Is it not possible to identify that you have selected the all value, and retrieve all the values again in the action page?

Comment: You could also create a multiple select, it you would like more than one choice.

Comment: What is the issue/error that you are experiencing? There seems to be nothing wrong with the way you are calling menuValues(). My guess is that the single quotes around each value in the double-quoted string is conflicting elsewhere in your code. Try using single-quotes instead of double-quotes and then escape the single-quotes around each value. OR instead of giving all 4 values as the option, you might simply say "ALL" in the dropdown.

Comment: @Mathnode I guess you're looking for `<select multiple="multiple">`. Or not? It's hard to get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear where is function frDrop() called and what does it's argument mean. But for my answer below, I'm assuming that $arr is the array that contains the dropdown options. So,

```
$arr = array(
"'value1','value2','value3','value4'",
'value1',
'value2',
'value3',
'value4'
);
```

Now, as I've guessed in my comment above, perhaps the single-quotes in the first array value - "'value1','value2','value3','value4'" - is conflicting with the single quotes in the  tag in the foreach() in function frDrop(). This is how the  tag will look like for the first value:

```
<option value=''value1','value2','value3','value4''>'value1','value2','value3','value4'</option>
```

You might try to escape the single quotes like this:

```
echo "<option value='".addslashes($value)."'>".$value."</option>";
```

OR, instead use single quotes to enclose your PHP statement:

```
echo '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped a lot thanks! You were spot in with what my output was doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function frDrop($arr,$frm,$dropTitle) {
    $temp   =''
    $temp.="<select name='".$frm."' id='".$frm."'><option value=''>".$dropTitle."...</option>";
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $temp.= "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
        }
    $temp.="</select>";
    }
echo $temp
```